# How can I adjust UINavigationBar tintColor to compensate for the new gradient effect in iOS6?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

In my app I'm tinting the navigation bar to a darker blue color.
The new gradient effects in iOS6 cause the navigation bar to appear much lighter (see below).

[image: UINavBar tints in iOS5 and iOS6]

If I adjust the color to be darker to compensate for iOS6, it will appear too dark in iOS5.

**What's the best way to make them appear the same (or nearly the same)?**

Detect the OS version and set different tint colors? Use a background image? Or is there a style setting I can use to change the gradient behavior?

Comment: This is also a problem if you want to include the navigation bar in your default launch image. Tinted or not, it's not going to match on the older OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could achieve this is to use a background image and set it using the Appearance proxy introduced in iOS 5.0.

If you create an image that is a thin vertical slice (e.g. width of 1px and height of 44px  and the doubled up retina images) and add it to your bundle, then you can then set the navigation bar background image for all navigation bars in your app once using the following method:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If you run that line of code when your app launches, e.g. in the following method of your appDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Then every navigationBar in your application will look identical.  The advantage of using an image like this is that regardless of OS version and any changes that may or may not come in the future, your application will always look the same.

Just be aware the Appearance proxy API was only added in iOS 5.0, so it wont work with older versions of iOS.  For a really good overview of the appearance proxy I'd recommend watching the WWDC 2011 video Session 114.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Background image is probably the best way to keep the exact same appearance. I was just surprised that the tintColor appearance had changed so drastically. I thought maybe I was missing something. I ended up just taking the easy way out and redesigning the UI slightly to something that works in both versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, and fixed it by taking out the tint color, and instead doing this:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Note that this means you'll then have to go change your user interface/xib file, because you changed the style to black translucent - I had to shove everything down 44 points.

Now the navigation bar should look the same in iOS 5 and iOS 6.